# Keeping only one record from spark dataframe. Not necessary distinct record

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I have the following data:

```
id  type  price
1    us    1.99
1    ca    2.99
2    ca    1.99
3    au    2.99 
3    us    3.99
3    ca    2.99
```

Basically, I want to get only one record per `id` and if is more than one, then I want to keep one with type, `us` over others.

Desired output:

```
id  type  price
1    us    1.99
2    ca    1.99
3    us    3.99
```

How can I do this using either `PySpark` or `SparkSQL` against a `Spark DataFrame` or a table?

Comment: Why don't you try this? `cols = ['id', 'type', 'price']
vals = [
    (1, 'us', 1.99),
    (1, 'ca', 2.99),
    (2, 'ca', 1.99),
    (3, 'au', 2.99),
    (3, 'us', 2.99),
    (3, 'us', 3.99),
    (3 ,'ca', 2.99)]

df = spark.createDataFrame(vals, cols)
d = df.groupBy('id').agg(first('type').alias('type'), first('price').alias('price')).orderBy('id') d.show()`

Comment: Thanks, but it's not recognizing 'first'.     Even tried. from pyspark.sql import functions as F     F.first.  still same thing.     how is that above query going to yield 'US' first?

Comment: Can you paste in the code you have tried so far?

Comment: it's the exact same code you gave me above, i am running in databrick note.  i'll post it tomorrow.  but it's literally the same.   i am thinking i might have to take this route.    Get all the 'US' from df and save it to df1.   Get all the 'CA' from df where id not exists from df1 and save it to df2.  Then merge df1 and df2.   would that work assuming only there are 'us' and 'ca' types?

Answer (score 0):

Window function with custom sorting can be used, in Scala below, guess, can be translated to Python:

```
// data
val df = List(
  (1, "us", 1.99),
  (1, "ca", 2.99),
  (2, "ca", 1.99),
  (3, "au", 2.99),
  (3, "us", 3.99),
  (3, "ca", 2.99))
  .toDF("id", "type", "price")

// action
val sorting = when($"type" === "us", 0).otherwise(1)
val window = Window.partitionBy($"id").orderBy(sorting)
val result = df
  .withColumn("sortIndex", row_number().over(window))
  .where($"sortIndex" === 1)
  .drop("sortIndex")
```

**Result:**

```
+---+----+-----+
|id |type|price|
+---+----+-----+
|1  |us  |1.99 |
|2  |ca  |1.99 |
|3  |us  |3.99 |
+---+----+-----+
```